# asp.net - ef - generic service/repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern

I'm using a service/repository pattern with a generic repository class `EFRepositoryBase<T>` where T : ModelBase, new()
T is the class from which all poco's used in ef inherit.
EFRepositoryBase has a method Read

```
public IQueryable<T> Read()
{
        try
        {
            return db.Set<T>();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new IRepositoryException();
        }
}
```

Each service inherits from `ServiceBase<T>` that has a repo property of type `EFRepository<T>`.

For performance reasons it is found that I better use a sql-view to display a list of orders because the list gets lots of data from other tables, has calculated fields, ... To test this I created a view in sql, poco (OrderIndexItem) to map to it, added a `DBset<OrderIndexItem>` vwOrderIndex to the context ... it all works fine. The issue is that for the moment I directly address db.vwOrderIndex in the service. Next step is to make it generic.

The idea is to add a static property to ModelBase that contains the type of the related 'view poco'.

```
public static Type IndexItemType { get; set; } = null;
```

and add a static constructor to Order to set that type

```
static  Order()
{
    IndexItemType = typeof(OrderIndexItem);
}
```

In the generic repository I added an extra method

```
    public IQueryable<TIndex> ReadIndex<TIndex>() where TIndex : ModelBase, IModelBaseIndexItem
    {
        try
        {
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new IRepositoryException();
        }
    }
```

The idea is to return a DbSet of the type associated to T via the static property IndexItemType.

Any thoughts?

Another acceptable solution might be just by using a naming convention of the associated IndexItemType f.e. Order - OrderIndexItem, Member - MemberIndexItem, ...

In both approaches the problem that I cannot solve: How to return the appropriate DbSet?

A third approach might be to change the EFRepositoryBase to

```
public class EFRepositoryBase<T, TIndex> : IRepository<T, TIndex> where T : ModelBase, new() where TIndex : ModelBase, IModelBaseIndexItem, new()
```

Though the impact on the code is huge, so I prefer not to use this approach unless it is the only one.

Comment: What _specifically_ is the problem? If you are just after general design advice, this is the wrong forum I'm afraid.

Comment: No general pattern advice. Given that order has a static property holding its associated poco for the view. How to return the dbset of that associated type in the generic repository.

Comment: Reflection. You can't parameterize generics at runtime.

Comment: Reflection does not work because the value of the static property is unknown at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I went for the following solution to not limit the repository to just one type of view per ModelBase POCO.

```
   public IQueryable<TSqlView> ReadSqlView<TSqlView>() where TSqlView : ISqlViewItem, new()
    {
        try
        {
            return (IQueryable<TSqlView>)Db.Set( typeof(TSqlView));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new IRepositoryException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A working solution using naming conventions :

```
public IQueryable<IModelBaseIndexItem> ReadIndex()
{
    try
    {
        Type TIndexItem = typeof(T).Assembly.GetType(typeof(T).FullName + "IndexItem");
        return (IQueryable<IModelBaseIndexItem>) db.Set(TIndexItem);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new IRepositoryException();
    }
}
```